# How to roll up SQL data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sql statement:

```
 SELECT
    Distinct UserId, A.TId, Branch ,Operation, FormId, A.ReportRefreshDate, UserType=Case When U.Designer=1 Then 'Designer' When U.Respondent=1 Then 'Respondent' END
FROM Activities A
INNER JOIN Users 
    ON LOWER(Users.UserPName) = LOWER(A.UserId)
INNER JOIN ActiviesUserTypes U
    ON Operation = U.ActionName
WHERE 
A.TId=4
AND
Users.Branch='LLA'
AND
(U.Designer=1 OR U.Respondent=1)
AND
A.ReportRefreshDate between DateAdd(DD,-200,GETDATE() ) and GETDATE()
```

This returns the following dummy / sample data:

```
UserId  TId Branch  Operation      FormId   ReportRefreshDate       UserType
jja     4   LLA     CreateResponse x21      2021-08-25 07:18:06.000 Respondent
asdf    4   LLA     ExportForm     f22      2021-08-25 07:18:06.000 Designer
38fa    4   LLA     ViewForm       2ay      2021-08-25 07:18:06.000 Designer
arb     4   LLA     CreateResponse x21      2021-08-29 07:18:06.000 Respondent
rtbs    4   LLA     CreateResponse f22      2021-08-29 07:18:06.000 Respondent
vfaa    4   LLA     ViewForm       2ay      2021-08-29 07:18:06.000 Designer
```

This is a good start.  But ultimately what I need to get back is totals for each user type per day.  so something like this:

```
ReportRefreshDate.       TotalDesigners.  TotalRespondents
2021-08-25 07:18:06.000  2                1
2021-08-29 07:18:06.000  1                2
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Comment: Check out Group By as starting point

Comment: Side note, do you need the `LOWER` functions in the clause `LOWER(Users.UserPName) = LOWER(A.UserId)`? If you are using a case insensitive collation, then the `LOWER` functions just cause performance degradation; as different cases of the same character(s) will match. I.e. `larnu = LARNU` resolves to `TRUE`. If you are using a case sensitive collation, then if the values have different cases they are, by definition, different and should not be matched. If you *do* want to compare the `LOWER` values to each other in a case sensitive collation, you should be using (`PERSISTED`) computed columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
with cte as (
    <query here>
)
select ReportRefreshDate,
       sum(case when UserType = 'Designer' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalDesigner,
       sum(case when UserType = 'Respondent' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalRespondents
from cte c
group by ReportRefreshDate;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that says 'cte ' is not a recognized table hints option

Comment: I did get it working.  Different syntax but borrowed from your idea / suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I used Pivot. Update: I removed Distinct on your query after  Charlieface feedback.

```
  SELECT 'count' AS user_type,   
      [Respondent], [Designer] 
    FROM  
    ( 
       SELECT
     UserId, A.TId, Branch ,Operation, FormId, A.ReportRefreshDate, UserType=Case When U.Designer=1 Then 'Designer' When U.Respondent=1 Then 'Respondent' END
FROM Activities A
INNER JOIN Users 
    ON LOWER(Users.UserPName) = LOWER(A.UserId)
INNER JOIN ActiviesUserTypes U
    ON Operation = U.ActionName
WHERE 
A.TId=4
AND
Users.Branch='LLA'
AND
(U.Designer=1 OR U.Respondent=1)
AND
A.ReportRefreshDate between DateAdd(DD,-200,GETDATE() ) and GETDATE()
    
    ) AS SourceTable  
    PIVOT  
    (  
      COUNT(UserType)  
      FOR UserType IN ([Respondent], [Designer])  
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: ah i didnt know that. thanks for feedback.

Comment: Sorry I mean you can write `COUNT(UserType)` you can't do `COUNT(*)` but the result is the same

Comment: i did it. do you think its better now ? @Charlieface